# node js not accepting hyphen in json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, discord.js

I am attempting to get a value from a JSON reply from an API in Node.js.
The basics of the reply is

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "playerSeason",
        "attributes": {
            "gameModeStats": {
                "duo": {
                    ...
                },
                "duo-fpp": {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Imagine that there is actually the right number of closing brackets and everything lines up as it should.

I am currently using

```
    let data=body.data.attributes.gameModeStats;
    let duos=data.duo;
    let duo_fpp=data.duo-fpp;
```

but `data.duo-fpp` appears as subtracting `fpp` from `data.duo`.

How do I appropriately reference `data.duo-fpp`?

Comment: try `let duo_fpp = data['duo-fpp'];`

Comment: it says `[ts] identifier expected` in VS Code